# Mango sdk for gaming applcations

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

can any one share the News about the Mango SDK updates?

Is it feasible to develop the gaming applications?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good summary of what's new in the "codename mango" SDK at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637516(v=vs.92).aspx

Developing games for Windows Phone 7 has always been feasible.
You can find more at http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment